# Permanently apply bootstrap theme

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, user-interface, themes

I have system which I incorporate bootstrap themes like on this one:

http://bootswatch.com/default/

So they can choose theme but when they refresh it will go back to default that I set to. Is there a way that when they choose a theme it will stay the same even after refresh?

Here's my code:

jQuery:

```
var themes = {
"default": "//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css",
"amelia" : "//bootswatch.com/amelia/bootstrap.min.css",
"cerulean" : "//bootswatch.com/cerulean/bootstrap.min.css",
"cosmo" : "//bootswatch.com/cosmo/bootstrap.min.css",
"cyborg" : "//bootswatch.com/cyborg/bootstrap.min.css",
"flatly" : "//bootswatch.com/flatly/bootstrap.min.css",
"journal" : "//bootswatch.com/journal/bootstrap.min.css",
"readable" : "//bootswatch.com/readable/bootstrap.min.css",
"simplex" : "//bootswatch.com/simplex/bootstrap.min.css",
"slate" : "//bootswatch.com/slate/bootstrap.min.css",
"spacelab" : "//bootswatch.com/spacelab/bootstrap.min.css",
"united" : "//bootswatch.com/united/bootstrap.min.css"
}



$(function(){
var themesheet = $('<link href="'+themes['simplex']+'" rel="stylesheet" />');
themesheet.appendTo('head');
$('.theme-link').click(function(){
   var themeurl = themes[$(this).attr('data-theme')]; 
    themesheet.attr('href',themeurl);
});
});
```

My dropdown in html:

```
<li class="dropdown">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></i> Themes <b class="caret"></b></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#" data-theme="default" class="theme-link">Default</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" data-theme="amelia" class="theme-link">Amelia</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" data-theme="cerulean" class="theme-link">Cerulean</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" data-theme="cosmo" class="theme-link">Cosmo</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" data-theme="cyborg" class="theme-link">Cyborg</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" data-theme="flatly" class="theme-link">Flatly</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" data-theme="journal" class="theme-link">Journal</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" data-theme="readable" class="theme-link">Readable</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" data-theme="simplex" class="theme-link">Simplex</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" data-theme="slate" class="theme-link">Slate</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" data-theme="spacelab" class="theme-link">Spacelab</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" data-theme="united" class="theme-link">United</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: Store current theme as a cookie and read after refresh.

Comment: @hopkins-matt how do I do that? Can you provide instructions? Thanks

Comment: Do you have a working example of the above code somewhere? It did not appear that the above code was on your site.

Comment: @hopkins-matt Here is a similar example of what I currently have, http://jsfiddle.net/82AsF/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JS below will allow you to utilize cookies for storing your theme information. I will note that I set the cookie expiration date a week out from the time it is set. It can be set for any amount of time, I just figure a week would be a good starting point. This script checks for the cookie every time it is ran. If the cookie does not exist it will load the `default` theme. Otherwise, it will display the theme based on the cookie. Every time the theme is changed it changes the cookie information.

**JS:**

```
var themes = {
    "default": "//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css",
    "amelia" : "//bootswatch.com/amelia/bootstrap.min.css",
    "cerulean" : "//bootswatch.com/cerulean/bootstrap.min.css",
    "cosmo" : "//bootswatch.com/cosmo/bootstrap.min.css",
    "cyborg" : "//bootswatch.com/cyborg/bootstrap.min.css",
    "flatly" : "//bootswatch.com/flatly/bootstrap.min.css",
    "journal" : "//bootswatch.com/journal/bootstrap.min.css",
    "readable" : "//bootswatch.com/readable/bootstrap.min.css",
    "simplex" : "//bootswatch.com/simplex/bootstrap.min.css",
    "slate" : "//bootswatch.com/slate/bootstrap.min.css",
    "spacelab" : "//bootswatch.com/spacelab/bootstrap.min.css",
    "united" : "//bootswatch.com/united/bootstrap.min.css"
}

$(function(){
    function getCookie(c_name) {
        if (document.cookie.length > 0) {
            c_start = document.cookie.indexOf(c_name + "=");
            if (c_start != -1) {
                c_start = c_start + c_name.length + 1;
                c_end = document.cookie.indexOf(";", c_start);
                if (c_end == -1) c_end = document.cookie.length;
                return unescape(document.cookie.substring(c_start, c_end));
            }
        }
        return "default";
    }

    function setCookie(c_name, value) {
        var exdate = new Date();
        exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + 7);
        document.cookie = c_name + "=" + escape(value) + ";path=/;expires=" + exdate.toUTCString();
    }

    var setTheme = getCookie('setTheme');

    var themesheet = $('<link href="'+themes[getCookie('setTheme')]+'" rel="stylesheet" />');

    themesheet.appendTo('head');

    $('.theme-link').click(function(){
        var themeurl = themes[$(this).attr('data-theme')]; 
        setCookie('setTheme', $(this).attr('data-theme'));
        themesheet.attr('href',themeurl);
    });
});
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/hopkins_matt/82AsF/127/

Comment: Thank you so much! Works perfect! I have a questin though, when trying to go to other pages the previous theme will still load by a miliseconds duration then change to the selected theme. Why is that?

Comment: When you say other pages what do you mean? Other pages previously visited? Remember the browser may have a cached version of the page that is loading temporarily until the javascript overrides the `<link>` tag after a few milliseconds. Try clearing your cache to simulate a new visitor and see if it still occurs.

Comment: Hi. It's ok now. You're right. Might be the cache :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try using jQuery's `localStorage`.  Here is an example that includes a dropwdown.  Whenever the user clicks one of the dropdown options, the theme changes and is saved.

**jQuery**

```
if(localStorage.theme)
    $('link#theme').attr('href', localStorage.theme);

$('#teal').click(function() {
    $('link#theme').attr('href', "src/components/styles/mainTeal.css");
    localStorage.theme = "mainTeal.css";
})

$('#gray').click(function() {
    $('link#theme').attr('href', "src/components/styles/mainGray.css");
    localStorage.theme = "mainGray.css";
})

$('#violet').click(function() {
    $('link#theme').attr('href', "src/components/styles/mainViolet.css");
    localStorage.theme = "mainViolet.css";
})

$('#plum').click(function() {
    $('link#theme').attr('href', "src/components/styles/mainPlum.css");
    localStorage.theme = "mainPlum.css";
})
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="btn-group">
    <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" type="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        Themes <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu center">
        <div class="btn-teal btn-sm" id="teal">Teal</div>
        <div class="btn-gray btn-sm" id="gray">Gray</div>
        <div class="btn-plum btn-sm" id="plum">Plum</div>
        <div class="btn-violet btn-sm" id="violet">Violet</div>
    </div>
    <div id="themes"></div>
</div>
```

**and in the `<head>`**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" id="theme" href="" type="text/css">
```